# How to add a body text to a multipart email in python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, sendmail, mime

I am successfully sending mails with attachment using python 2. But the mails still have no body content.

Can someone please tell me how can I add a body text along with attachment and subject.

My current code is:

```
import smtplib, os
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import Encoders
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


SUBJECT = "Email Data"
emaillist=['xyz@hotmail.com']
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['Subject'] = 'SUBJECT '
msg['From'] = 'abc@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = ', '.join(emaillist)



part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")

part.set_payload(open('C:'+os.sep+'Desktop'+os.sep+'temp1.txt', `"rb").read())`
Encoders.encode_base64(part)

part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="output.txt"')

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login("abc@gmail.com", "password")

server.sendmail(msg['From'], emaillist , msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html :

```
text = "Here is the message body"
html = """
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>here is some html<br>
       Here is some link <a href="https://www.python.org">link</a>.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
```

Insert this after `msg.attach(part)`

Comment: I tried that and it threw the this error: ** 'Cannot attach additional subparts to non-multipart/*')
email.errors.MultipartConversionError: Cannot attach additional subparts to non-multipart/* **

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand your problem completely. Updated the answer.